# Regex: match pattern after some pattern

Tags: regex

I have strings:

```
Word AB70 60.1 Another
Word AB70 60 Another
Word AB70 D65.1 Another
Word AB70(-20) D65.1 Another
Word AB-70 D65.1 Another
```

I need to get `60.1` or `60` or `65.1` without D letter (letter could be any)

My thoughts was on regex

```
AB-?\d+(?:\(-?\d+\))?\K\d+(?:\.\d+)
```

What I was thinking is to find AB70, forget it and get next match with `\d+(?:\.\d+)`

but it is not working... what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try `AB\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*[A-Za-z]*\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?`, see https://regex101.com/r/swmaml/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks Wiktor it is working! so you take letter too and forget all the match... didn't thought about this. Is there any easier way to forget earlier match and start finding new pattern from that place?

Comment: I suggested the pattern above because you attempted to write it like this. You provided no requirements, and there is no way to guess how to do something better if no requirements are provided. "Match me that string" is not a requirement. You accepted a regex that [matches very funny inputs](https://regex101.com/r/NjTHqI/2/), not sure you really want them. Then, you may even use a shorter `AB\S*\D*(\d[\d.]*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(?:) represents a non-capturing group in regex, so you wouldn't get the next match with `\d+(?:\.\d+)`

Assuming the pattern you are matching always starts with AB, the regex below should work. It looks for AB, followed by any amount of non-white space, non-digit characters. The capture group captures 0 or more digit characters, optionally with a decimal point, followed by 0 or more digits.

`AB\S*\D*(\d*\.?\d*)`

Comment: this was best solution, I just would need to forget all the string before with this: AB\S*\D*\K\d*\.?\d*

Answer (score 1):

You did not take into account the spaces and letter:

```
AB-?\d+(?:\(-?\d+\))?\s*[A-Za-z]*\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/swmaml/2)

**Details**

- `AB` - an `AB` char sequence
- `-?\d+(?:\(-?\d+\))?` - an optional `-`, 1+ digits and then an optional sequence of `(`, an optional `-`, 1+ digits and `)` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `[A-Za-z]*` - 0 or more letters
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `\d+`  - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ digits after.